# Use of uniformity of a limit for proof of continuity when right continuity is known

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity

Consider a function $f: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that, for any $t \in (0, \infty)$
$$
\lim_{h \downarrow 0 } \,  \, (  f(t+h) - f(t) )=  O(h),
$$
namely that the function $f$ is right continuous. I read in a book that if O(h) is uniform in $t$, then we can replace, $t=s-h$ and deduce that, for any $s \in (0, \infty)$,
$$
\lim_{h \uparrow 0 }(  f(s) - f(s-h) )=  O(h),
$$
Namely that the function is also left continuous. How us uniformity in t used?

Answer (score 1):

You have that there is $C>0$ and $\delta >0$ s.t. for all $t>0$,
$$|f(t+h)-f(t)|\leq C|h|,\quad |h|\leq \delta .$$

Then if $u=t+h$ and thus $t=u-h$, we get $$|f(u)-f(u-h)|=|f(t+h)-f(t)|\leq C|h|.$$

Taking $h\to 0$ yields the wished result.

Comment: What could happen without uniform continuity?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm: if $C$ depend on $t$, then if $t_h=u-h$ $|f(u)-f(u-h)|=|f(t_h+h)-f(t_h)|\leq C_{t_h}|h|$. So, if $h\to 0$, then $C_{t_h}$ can goes to infinity (and thus $f(t_h+h)-f(t_h)$ will not converges to $0$ hen $h\to 0$.)